# unable to install latest android version with ionic platform add android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to install latest android version but whenever I run `ionic platform add android` the cli install android version 6.

However if i do `ionic platform add android@6.1.0` it install version 6.1.10 but i want to install the latest version with `ionic platform add android` command.

How can i install android version > 6 with this command.

My config.xml conf is:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="25" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the latest version by running

```
  cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```

From their [site](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/28/android-release.html)

> This release will have to be explicitly added until the upcoming cordova@7 release, where it will be pinned as the default android platform.

Comment: but cordova 7 is released though. how to make it default

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this command for latest platform:

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```